# Format HTML ordered list numbers in iText 5

Tags: html, css, pdf-generation, itext, xmlworker

I am using Java to convert HTML input into PDF using iText5 (com.itextpdf.tool xmlworker ver 5.5.10). I have an ordered list that needs to be displayed in a specific font. My problem is that I am not able to change the font or size of the list numbers to match the content of the list items. For below HTML, numbers 7. 8. 9. and 10. are incorrect in generated PDF. How do I change the font for the numbers?

HTML input:

```
<ol start="7">
  <li>seventh entry</li>
  <li>eight entry</li>
  <li>ninth entry</li>
<li>tenth entry</li>
</ol>
```

Java source:

```
private Paragraph htmlToPdf(String htmlStr) throws PdfException {
ElementList elements = new ElementList();

String fontTypeNormal = FontProvider.FontType.BRODTEXT_NORMAL.toString();  //"Frutiger LT Std"
String fontSizeNormal = "font-size: 11pt";

fontProvider.registerFont(FontProvider.FontType.BRODTEXT_NORMAL); //method in other class. using FontFactory.register(). This works.

String cssStr = "p {font-family: '" + fontTypeNormal + "'; " + fontSizeNormal + "} ul { list-style: disc; font-family: '" + fontTypeNormal
        + "'; } li { font-family: '" + fontTypeNormal + "'; " + fontSizeNormal + "} ol { font-family: '" + fontTypeNormal + "'; } ";


try {
    elements = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(htmlStr, cssStr);
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("Failed to parse HTML...");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Paragraph htmlParagraph = new Paragraph();

htmlParagraph.add(element);
}

return htmlParagraph;
}
```

Here is a Picture of PDF part that is not working: PDF output

[image]